# FragmentManager(v4) not removing fragments from mCreatedMenus

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, leakcanary

LeakCanary identified leak in my code

```
* classifieds.yalla.features.ad.page.seller.SellerAdPageFragment has leaked:
* GC ROOT android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1.this$0 (anonymous subclass of com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub)
* references android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
* references android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.mContext
* references classifieds.yalla.features.host.HostActivity.fragNavController
* references com.ncapdevi.fragnav.FragNavController.mFragmentManager
* references android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mCreatedMenus
* references java.util.ArrayList.elementData
* references array java.lang.Object[].[0]
* leaks classifieds.yalla.features.ad.page.seller.SellerAdPageFragment instance
```

But when I looked in the `FragmentManagerImpl`

I didn't found when `FragmentManagerImpl.mCreatedMenus` getting cleared. The only code I found is when new fragments getting added. Shouldn't it be managed somehow?

```
public boolean dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        boolean show = false;
        ArrayList<Fragment> newMenus = null;
        if (mAdded != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<mAdded.size(); i++) {
                Fragment f = mAdded.get(i);
                if (f != null) {
                    if (f.performCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)) {
                        show = true;
                        if (newMenus == null) {
                            newMenus = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
                        }
                        newMenus.add(f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (mCreatedMenus != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<mCreatedMenus.size(); i++) {
                Fragment f = mCreatedMenus.get(i);
                if (newMenus == null || !newMenus.contains(f)) {
                    f.onDestroyOptionsMenu();
                }
            }
        }

        mCreatedMenus = newMenus;

        return show;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post `SellerAdPageFragment`?

Comment: @azizbekian it's quite big. My point is that mCreatedMenus not getting cleared when fragment removed, it reassigned upon creation new fragment with the menu and then old fragments in mCreatedMenus will be released

Comment: That's because you somehow are keeping a reference to the fragment.

Comment: fragmentManager keeping reference in this field  `ArrayList<Fragment> mCreatedMenus;`

Comment: I understood your point and the code in FragmentManagerImpl; But how do you make sure that mCreatedMenus is causing the memory leaks? Do you see any other logs?

Answer (score 7):

This issue is still relevant nowadays on androidx.fragment v1.10 (so Nov. 2019), so here's some insight to it.

Assume setHasOptionsMenu() is called with a true value for a fragment f.
When f is detached, the Fragment Manager (FM) associated with f will not handle the change implied on the menu.
Remember that the menu is potentially affected by multiple fragments hosted by the same FM. The fact that one of them, f, got detached should have caused the FM to reconstruct the menu, but then again, this is not handled.
Further more, when f is detached, resources associated with f in the context of supporting the menu are also not cleaned up.
In particular, onDestroyOptionsMenu() is not called on f and the FM keeps a reference to f in its list of fragments that provide menu options.

Until Google fixes the fragment manager to remove the leaked fragment from that list, some options are:

- Live with the leaked fragment.  When the activity gets destroyed, the fragment manager will be cleared out and the fragment will get claimed by the GC then.
- Don't use the setHasOptionsMenu() mechanism. You could for example, come up with your own menu implemenation.
- Use reflection to remove the fragment from that list.  Sure reflection is not ideal, but leaking a fragment is much worse.
  In the otherwise leaking fragment, add something like the following

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // get the fragment manager associated with this fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager != null) {
        try {
            Field field = 
                fragmentManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCreatedMenus");
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.get(fragmentManager) instanceof ArrayList) {
                ArrayList fragments = (ArrayList)field.get(fragmentManager);

                if (fragments != null && fragments.remove(this)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Yay, no leak today");
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | 
                 IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Naturally, this solution is fragile when fragment related code changes, however, this is testable. In addition if proguard is used, you would want to make sure obfuscation is avoided for that field, so you could add proguard directive like this:

`-keep class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl { *; }`

Or even better, try to figure out how to use -keepclassmembers for keeping mCreatedMenus.

Comment: Code shrinker should automatically keep the field accessed through reflection, don't quote me on that.

Comment: I'm trying this with `parentFragmentManager` but it fails saying the field doesn't exist... Any advise?

Comment: I have found the google issue tracker entry for this problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131537919 They were still missing a minimal sample there to fix the issue, I've now provided one. Feel free to add to the conversation there if you have more info on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

It is a leak in the Android SDK. Take a look at [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125819).

The issue is fixed if you update to Target-Support-26.0.0-beta1 support lib in your gradle app file (`build.gradle`).

If for some reasons you cannot update to **supportLibVersion>=26-beta1**, then there is a workaround:

```
public class FragmentUtils { 

    /** 
     * Hack to force update the LoaderManager's host to avoid a memory leak in retained/detached fragments. 
     * Call this in {@link Fragment#onAttach(Activity)} 
     */ 
    public static void updateLoaderManagerHostController(Fragment fragment) { 
        if (fragment.mHost != null) { 
            fragment.mHost.getLoaderManager(fragment.mWho, fragment.mLoadersStarted, false); 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * This hack is to prevent the root loader manager to leak previous instances of activities 
     * accross rotations. It should be called on activities using loaders directly (not via a fragments). 
     * If the activity has fragment, you also have to also {@link #updateLoaderManagerHostController(Fragment)} above 
     * for each fragment. 
     * Call this in {@link FragmentActivity#onCreate} 
     * 
     * @param activity an actvity that uses a loader and leaks on rotation. 
     */ 
    public static void updateLoaderManagerHostController(FragmentActivity activity) { 
        if (activity.mFragments != null) { 
            try { 
                final Field mHostField = activity.mFragments.getClass().getDeclaredField("mHost"); 
                mHostField.setAccessible(true); 
                FragmentHostCallback mHost = (FragmentHostCallback) mHostField.get(activity.mFragments); 
                mHost.getLoaderManager("(root)", false, true /* the 2 last params are not taken into account*/); 
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with androidX FragmentManager.

Fixed the leak by calling this after a fragment transaction.  This method goes inside an activity.

```
    private fun clearFragmentManagersAddedMenus() {
        Handler(mainLooper).post {
            val field = FragmentActivity::class.java.getDeclaredField("mFragments")
            field.isAccessible = true
            (field.get(this) as FragmentController).dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(null, null)
        }
    }
```